# Encode module and inverted commas

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

I am scraping a web page, and extracting a specific section from it. That section includes inverted commas (`’`, character 146). I'm trying to print my extracted data to a text file, but it's giving me `â€™` instead of the inverted comma. I have tried the following:

- `$content =~ s/’/'/g;`
- `my $invComma = chr 146;
  $content =~ s/$invComma/'/g;`
- `$content =~ s/\x{0092}/'/g;`

None of it has worked. I can't `decode('UTF-8', $content)` because it has wide characters. When I try to `encode('UTF-8', $content)` the `â€™` changes to `Ã¢Â€Â™` instead. I have already tried `use utf8` as well, to no effect.

I know that my text file viewer can display inverted commas, because I printed one to a test file and opened it. The problem is therefore in my script.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

*UPDATE*: I am able to do `$content =~ s/â€™/'/g` to replace it with a simple apostrophe, but I still don't know why nothing else works. I'd also like a fix that actually solves the problem, instead of just solving one of the symptoms.

*UPDATE 2*: I have been informed by [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) that the character is actually `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` and changed my regex to use `chr 0x2019` which now works.

Comment: However you're fetching the contents of the webpage, it's misinterpreting the encoding ­— but you didn't include that part of the code in your question.

Comment: I'm using LWP::Simple's get(_URL_) method. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Are you sure the _inverted comma_ is 146? I just copy-and-pasted it from your OP into my editor, saved it, did `hexdump -C` and got `e2 80 99`.

Comment: @PerlDog right you are, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: I pasted it into a perl script that just printed ord "’" and it gave me 146.

Comment: This character: `’` is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, Unicode 0x2019. I've seen the term "inverted comma" used to refer to some kind of quotation mark, but it doesn't seem to be common usage (maybe it's UK-specific?). There is no "INVERTED COMMA" character defined by Unicode. And chr(146) is a control character in Unicode ("PRIVATE USE TWO") -- though it is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: If `$content =~ s/â€™/'/g` works, then `$content` is encoded using UTF-8, so you need to do `$content = decode('UTF-8', $content);` first.

Comment: Tried that, it tells me "cannot decode string with wide characters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in my script, it was in my editor. The script works properly, and the question is based on false pretenses. I was using gVim on Windows, which did not play nicely with Unicode. My script was properly decoding the content, but when I opened the output file in gVim, it mangled the text and displayed it incorrectly. My attempts to use regular expressions to change the characters failed because I was using the wrong codepoint - it wasn't 0x92, it was 0x2019. This was another failing of gVim. Thanks to [hobbs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/152948) and [ikegami](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/589924) for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

The character you're trying to replace is only 0x92 / 146 in the Windows-1252 encoding. Perl uses Unicode, where that character is `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, aka `"\x{2019}"`, `chr(0x2019)`, or `chr(8217)`.

Comment: So I should look for the proper _unicode_ codepoint online and do the replacements that way? Can I use the Encode module on my input instead? If so, how?

Comment: @Lilith you don't need the Encode module, your input has already been decoded correctly (using the Encode module) by LWP. LWP::Simple uses the `decoded_content` method of HTTP::Response.

Comment: So how do I make my script print it correctly? I marked the output file as utf8, using IO::All, then printed the output directly. It showed up as "â€™" instead. I _could_ just add replacements for the three characters (open/close double quotes and right single quote), but I'd rather solve the problem than the symptom.

Comment: @Lilith showed up as that in what? Are you opening the output file in something that isn't unicode-aware? Or are you doing something else that's fooling encoding detection? It's really hard to tell, other than that the problem isn't where you think it is.

Comment: I'm using gVim on Windows, think that's it?

Comment: @Lilith vim should work just fine, but it might have different default assumptions on windows. Try running `:e ++enc=utf8` and see how things look. (Edit: yeah, it looks like vim on windows has silly legacy defaults. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114388/discussion-between-lilith-and-hobbs).

Answer (score 4):

Start by finding out what `$content` contains. You can use the following:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
warn(Dumper($content));
```

---

If you get the following, `$content` is decoded

```
$VAR1 = "...\x{2019}...";
```

Any of the following will work.

```
use utf8;  # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
$content =~ s/’/'/g;
```

```
$content =~ s/\x{2019}/'/g;
```

```
$content =~ s/\N{U+2019}/'/g;
```

```
$content =~ s/\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}/'/g;
```

---

If you get the following, `$content` is encoded using UTF-8.

```
$VAR1 = "...\342\200\231...";
```

Start by decoding the value of `$content` using either of the following:

```
utf8::decode($content) or die;
```

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );
$content = decode_utf8($content);
```

Then use any of the solutions for decoded content (above).

---

If you get the following, `$content` is encoded using cp1252.

```
$VAR1 = "...\222...";
```

Start by decoding the value of `$content`.

```
use Encode qw( decode );
$content = decode("cp1252", $content);
```

Then use any of the solutions for decoded content (above).

---

By the way, `â€™` is what the UTF-8 encoding of `’` (`E2 80 99`) would look like if decoded as cp1252.